# Validation for radio button with empty textbox in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have several questions with the radio buttons in my form with the textboxes, there are two radio buttons "Yes" and "No", if I select Yes below textboxes are enabled its done, but if I select "No" textboxes are disabled but when I click submit button its showing "please enter all the details", it's showing because I have written validation for textboxes. But if I clicked submit button it should save successfully and the value should be save as "No" in database.

I have tried something below is the code.

```
if ((txt1Yes1.Text.Equals(string.Empty)||(txt1Yes2.Text.Equals(string.Empty))))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Please Enter All The Details");
 }

string smoke = txt1Yes1.Text + "-" + txt1Yes2.Text;
if (rbtnsmkYes.Checked == true)
{
  cmdsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@smokeYN", smoke);
 }

 else
  cmdsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@smokeYN", "No");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ((txt1Yes1.Text.Equals(string.Empty)||(txt1Yes2.Text.Equals(string.Empty))))
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Please Enter All The Details");
     }

SqlParameter parm= new SqlParameter("@smokeYN",SqlDbType.VarChar) ; 
    string smoke = txt1Yes1.Text + "-" + txt1Yes2.Text;
    if (rbtnsmkYes.Checked)
    {      
        parm.Value=smoke ;
        parm.Direction =ParameterDirection.Input ; 
        cmdsql.Parameters.Add(parm);
    }

   else if(rbtnsmkNo.Checked))
    {
         parm.Value="No";
        parm.Direction =ParameterDirection.Input ; 
        cmdsql.Parameters.Add(parm);
    }
```